# Is it possible to export a value of an variable from one javascript to an other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, export

I have made a Web page using jquery and php where all files are used in a modular style. Now I have two JavaScript files which must communicate with each other. One Script generates a variable (*id_menu_bar*) which contains a number. I want that this variable gets transported to the second JavaScript and is used there.

How do I make that?

Here the Script

**menu_bar.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function wrapper_action(id_menu_bar) {
  $(".wrapper").animate({height: "0px"});
  $("#changer p").click(function() {
    $(".wrapper").animate({height: "300px"});
  });
}

  $("#select_place li").live("click", function() {
  var wrapper_id = $(".wrapper").attr("id");
  var id_place = this.id;

  if (wrapper_id != "place")
    {
    $("#select_level li").remove();
      $("#select_building").load("menu_bar/menu_bar_building.php?placeitem="+id_place, function() {
        $("#select_building li").click(function() {
        var id_building = this.id;

          if (wrapper_id != "building")
            {
            $("#select_level").load("menu_bar/menu_bar_level.php?buildingitem="+id_building, function() {
              $("#select_level li").click(function() {
                var id_level = this.id;
                wrapper_action(id_level);
              });
            });

            }
          else if (wrapper_id == "building")
            {wrapper_action(id_building);}
        });
      });

      }
   else if (wrapper_id == "place")
    {wrapper_action(id_place);}
   });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the variable `id_menu_bar` is in global scope then it can be used by another script on the page.

jQuery's [`$.data()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data) is also good for storing data against elements and means that you do not need to use a global variable and pollute the global namespace.

**EDIT:**

In response to your comment, there is a difference in how you declare variables that determines how they are scoped in JavaScript.

**Global Variables**

Outside of a function declaring a variable like

```
var myVariable;
```

or

```
myVariable;
```

will make no difference - both variables will have global scope. In fact, the second approach will give a variable global scope, even inside of a function. For example

```
function firstFunction() {
    // Local scope i.e. scoped to firstFunction
    var localVariable; 

    // Global scope i.e. available to all other JavaScript code running
    // in the page
    globalVariable = "I'm not really hiding";
}

function secondFunction() {
    // I can access globalVariable here but only after
    // firstFunction has been executed
    alert(globalVariable); // alerts I'm not really hiding
}
```

The difference in this scenario is that the alert will fail and not show the value for `globalVariable` upon execution of `secondFunction()` until `firstFunction()` has been executed, since this is where the variable is declared. Had the variable been declared outside of any function, the alert would have succeeded and shown the value of `globalVariable`

**Using jQuery.data()**

Using this command, you can store data in a cache object for an element. I would recommend looking at the source to see how this achieved, but it is pretty neat. Consider

```
  function firstFunction() {
      $.data(document,"myVariable","I'm not really hiding"); 
      globalVariable = "I'm not hiding";
  }

  function secondFunction() {
      // alerts "I'm not really hiding" but only if firstFunction is executed before
      // secondFunction
      alert($.data(document, "myVariable"));

      // alerts "I'm not hiding" but only if firstFunction is executed before
      // secondFunction
      alert(globalVariable);
  }
```

in this scenario, a string value `"I'm not really hiding"` is stored against the document object using the key string `myVariable` in `firstFunction`. This value can then be retrieved from the cache object anywhere else in the script. Attempting to read a value from the cache object without having first set it will yield `undefined`.

Take a look at this **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/otoso)** for more details.

For reasons not to use Global Variables, check out this [article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: Yeap- @elhombre you need to think in terms of scope instead of "files". Reading something like this should help you- http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

Comment: @RichardOD Thanks very much for the enlightening comment. I think there will not be a way around making files, because that would just lead to one big File which makes editing individual features difficult.

Now I know in every File I am starting with a '$(document).ready(function()' so I am already in a scope and can't access the variables through an other Files.

How Do I make it possible to just start all the files in one scope '$(document).ready(function()' in a logical way?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to ve a JavaScript variable?

Can you store the information using the `.data()` function against a relevant element?