# How to initialize textbox to hide for first display and still have jquery work

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

So I now have the following jquery to hide or show a textbox based on specific values selected in a DropDownList.  This works except that I need the first display of the popup to always be hidden.  Since no index change was made in the drop down list, the following does not work for that.  If I code it as visible="false", then it always stays hidden.  How can I resolve this?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     var _CASE_RESERVE_ACTION = "317"; 
     var _LEGAL_RESERVE_ACTION = "318";

     function pageLoad() {

         $(".statusActionDDLCssClass").change(function() {
             var value = $(this).val();
             if (value == _CASE_RESERVE_ACTION || value == _LEGAL_RESERVE_ACTION) {
                 $(".statusActionAmountCssClass").attr("disabled", false);
                 $(".statusActionAmountCssClass").show();
             }
             else {
                 $(".statusActionAmountCssClass").attr("disabled", true);
                 $(".statusActionAmountCssClass").hide();
             }
         });
     }

</script>
```

Thank you,
Jim in Suwanee, GA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set

```
visible=false
```

.Net will not render it.  You can do

```
style="display:none;"
```

and .Net will render the tag properly but CSS will hide it from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `pageLoad` function

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {

$("input.statusActionAmountCssClass").hide();

.... rest of code .....

}
```

By the way, I would recommend using the selector `$("input.statusActionAmountCssClass"`) to get a jQuery object containing a reference to your input, otherwise jQuery will search ***all*** elements to match the CSS class `.statusActionAmountCssClass`

**EDIT:**

Another change that could also be made is to use jQuery's [`data()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data) to store the two global variables

```
$.data(window, "_CASE_RESERVE_ACTION","317"); 
$.data(window, "_LEGAL_RESERVE_ACTION","318");
```

then when you need them simply cache the value in a local variable inside the function

```
function someFunctionThatNeedsGlobalVariableValues() {

    var caseReserveAction = $.data(window, "_CASE_RESERVE_ACTION");
    var legalReserveAction = $.data(window, "_LEGAL_RESERVE_ACTION");
}
```

this way, the global namespace is not polluted. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305345/is-it-possible-to-export-a-value-of-an-variable-from-one-javascript-to-an-other/1305358#1305358) for more on `data()` command

Comment: Thank you for this soolution as well.  
And thanks for the "input" restriction!

Jim